# make NSRect selectable

Tags: cocoa, select

Is there a simple way to create a selectable NSRect in Cocoa? In need a rectangle that can be selected and stays selected after a mouse click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not as immediate as you would like, you may be interested in the management of tracking rectangles and tracking areas performed by [`NSView`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) class.

This mechanism allows you to define specific areas of your custom view. Then, an event is generated whenever the cursor enters or leaves the area, or a mouse button is pressed in this area (`-mouseEntered:`, `-mouseExited:`, `-mouseDown:`, `-mouseUp:`, `-mouseDragged:`, ... of [`NSResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class). This up to you to define what you want your application do in response to these events (set the rectangle as selected and display it accordingly).

Answer (score 2):

NSRect is just a struct with a position and size. It's not an object that can actually *do* anything or have any properties other than a width and height. It sounds like what you want is to create an NSView that can be selected. (Here's [Apple's Guide](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) on the subject.)

Answer (score 0):

For an example implementation of this, take a look at the Sketch example included with the Apple developer tools (look in /Developer/Examples/AppKit).  Sketch allows the user to create new graphics (including rectangles, but also ovals, lines, and text), select them, move them around in the document, etc.  In particular, you'll probably want to look at the SKTGraphic class, which represents a single graphic object in the document, and the SKTGraphicView class, which is an NSView subclass that perform the actual layout and drawing, handling mouse events for dragging views around, etc.